# Display XML data in message box

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, visual-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Subject>
  <Book>
    <Name>ASP.NET</Name>
    <Author>ABC</Author>
    <Published>2018</Published>
    <Price>$100</Price>
  </Book>
</Subject>
```

The above is the xml file I have, I need to display those values in Messsage Box using Windows Forms in C# without editing xml file and in the code I don't want to use XML nodes such as (name,Price..).

**Edit:**

What I have tried so far:

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
int i = 0;
string str = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                    @"C:\\Users\\15034\\Desktop\\Book.xml", 
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
xmldoc.Load(fs);
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Book");
for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{
    xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim(); 
    str = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

The output should be look like:

```
ASP.NET
ABC
2018
$100
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please avoid adding code in the question. Instead, you should [edit] your post to include it.

Comment: That's not valid XML - `<Subjects>` vs `</Subject>`. Correcting that and running your code (using XmlDocument instead of the obsolete XmlDataDocument) outputs the book name. Is that not the desired behaviour?

Comment: I am still looking for the solution .Please someone help me......!!!

Comment: How can i store the same xml values using Dictionaries or Collections in C# winforms ..??

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridview as follows:

```
 private void Display_Data(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      try
      {
          XmlReader xmlFile ;
          xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
      } 
  }
```

okay for displaying in message box use following:

```
 private void  Display_Message(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
     if ( ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
         xDoc.Load(ofd.FileName);
         MessageBox.Show(xDoc.SelectSingleNode("FATCAFileErrorNotification/NotificationContentTxt").InnerText);
     }
```

Comment: Yes @kish .. but i want  the output in message box ..can u please help me if u..???   thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using XDocument:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(yourxmlfile);

//Preparing string in readable format
var result = (from att in doc.Descendants("Book")
    select 
    string.Format("Name: {0}", att.Element("Name").Value) + Environment.NewLine +
    string.Format("Author: {0}", att.Element("Author").Value) + Environment.NewLine + 
    string.Format("Published: {0}", att.Element("Published").Value) + Environment.NewLine + 
    string.Format("Price: {0}", att.Element("Price").Value));

//Joining the result from XML
var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.ToArray());
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

As already mentioned by @stuartd in comments, your xml is invalid  with s missing in closing tag.

Comment: yes i am aware of that , but one thing i need the output values as one by one not as in one line.. Can u do that   @kashi_rock

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes i got it ..Can u do the same without including xml nodes in code ..?

Answer (score 0):

Using XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
int i = 0;
string str = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Books.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
xmldoc.Load(fs);
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Book");

for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Count-1; j++)
    {
        if (xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).Name == "Name")
            continue;
        xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText.Trim();
        str = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText.Trim();
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
}
```

Using XPath:

```
XPathDocument docNav = new XPathDocument("Books.xml");
XPathNavigator nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
foreach (var item in nav.Select(@"/Subjects/Book/Author"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for usefull info , but i want the output values to be displayed as one by one not as single line output

Comment: What you want to output? Provide an example for your desired output.